# TextView is trimmed by it's parent (RelativeLayout/FrameLayout)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am developing some kind of a scrollable horizontal chart. I have a RecyclerView.Adapter with view holder of two views:
1. View - will just represent a bar with defined height.
2. TextView - on the top of (1)View with angle -45 it should represent some data to which this column belongs.

Width of bar should be equal for each column, but text has different length.
But boundaries of parent (no metter is it Frame or Relative layouts are cutting off the rest of the text.

P.S. clipChildren and clipToPadding didn't help.

My .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="@dimen/chart_column_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<View
    android:id="@+id/cc_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cc_tagname"
    android:layout_above="@id/cc_progress"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: after all animations]
[image: with templates boundaries]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are just rotating the TextView. So, the TextView retaining its original height and width.

Try using this VerticalTextView :

```
`public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
 final boolean topDown;

 public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
  super(context, attrs);
  final int gravity = getGravity();
  if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
     setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
     topDown = false;
  }else
     topDown = true;
 }

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
   setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
  textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
  textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

  canvas.save();

  if(topDown){
     canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
     canvas.rotate(90);
  }else {
     canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
     canvas.rotate(-90);
  }


  canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

  getLayout().draw(canvas);
  canvas.restore();
  }
  }`
```

All you have to set the gravity of the text. By default, text is from top to bottom. If you set android:gravity="bottom", then it's drawn from bottom to top.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Maybe It can be a solution but only for -90 degrees (as on image) but for -45 it won't work.

Comment: You can change the angle at  canvas.rotate() method in VerticalTextView to whatever angle you want. But at -45 degrees it may ellipsis again if it try to cross the width of the parent view.

Comment: Yes, and this is what I am looking for "how to overlay parent's bounds?"

Comment: Then its little tough task but it is possible. I'm explaining the idea in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its little tough task but it is possible. I'm explaining idea how you can make it possible: –

You have make recyclerview wrap_content and keep it inside the relativelayout and the scrollview.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Now calculate the width of an item of the recylerview and add the textview in rlRoot at position (width * itemPosition). It places the textview at exact X position. Now to calculate Y coordinate, you can get height of the items as you are setting the bar height and Y position of the textView should be(rlRoot.getHeight()- itemHeight). And then give the whatever angle you want, it will never ellipsis. Repeat the loop for all the items.

I never tried it, but i guess, it will work with your efforts.

Comment: I think this may work fine, but looks kind of weird and spaghetti code will be everywhere. I mean, that I think something simplier should exist. If I won't get an answer in future several days I will mark this answer as true.

Answer (score 0):

Override OnMeasure of Textview and increase the height on super.OnMeasure method